# how to delete multiple row data using checkbox from datatable and database

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am new to jquery datatable i want to delete multiple row using which ever row checkbox is selected in datatable.Below code is not deleting data from database.If anybody know solution please help.Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#employee_data').dataTable();
        $('#delete').click(function () {
            if ($('.chkNumber:checked').length) {
                var id = '';
                $('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
                    id += $(this).val() + " ";
                });
                alert(id);
                $('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please select a checkbox');
            }
        });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: what are you getting in alert(id); ? if you are getting value in id then call ajax and remove that ids from database and reinitialize the datatable.

Comment: To delete it from `database` you need to write some server code too and make an ajax call to delete it from `database`.

Comment: first you need to get all id that you want to delete for example as comma seperated 1,2,3,4 etc and ajax call your method to delete this id from database and after update your datatable